# Keeping track of file opening

Tags: emacs

Is there an extension or easy way to hack Emacs to keep track of all file open and file save operations?
I looked at recentf, and it doesn't seem to work with multiple Emacs processes running in parallel.

BTW, I found a way to keep track of file save operations, using http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackupEachSave

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")
(require 'backup-each-save)
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'backup-each-save)
(setq backup-each-save-mirror-location "/usr/local/google/users/yaroslavvb/backups")
```

It saves backup on each save with timestamp in filename, so you can get list of all save operations by traversing backups tree

Comment: Just curious : why do you need several concurrent emacs processes (given the existence of [emacsclient](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Emacs-Server.html#Emacs-Server) ?)

Comment: @huitseeker: There are a bunch of reasons. From using a clean emacs process to the lack of concurrency (if you run a mail client for example).

Comment: Main reason has to do with managing buffers. I use separate Emacs session for each project, so I can easily see the files I have in the project. Also *Shell* and *Python* buffers can be per-project that way. Occasionally something breaks and I need to kill Emacs, but my other projects survive in their latest state

Answer (score 0):

There are hooks for visiting and saving files. You can use those to create some kind of common tracking function if you know elisp:

http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Standard-Hooks.html